# JavaScript error trapping is not reading 0 (zero)

Tags: javascript, error-handling

The JavaScript below just checks if there are 4 digits in a field or not and then warns if there isn't.

But for some reason, if I enter four zeros (0000) it takes that as an empty field and throws the warning.

Any idea how to fix this...??  I am no programmer but have put this code together after weeks of trial-and-error.

```
function validate(){
//  if ( (!isNaN($("#couponstart1").val())) || (!isNaN($("#couponstart2").val())) || (!isNaN($("#couponend1").val()))  || (!isNaN($("#couponend2").val()))  ) {
    var all_ok = true;
    var err_msg = "";
    var fld = "";

    if ( $("#couponstart1").val() == '' || $("#couponstart2").val() == '' || $("#couponend1").val() == '' || $("#couponend2").val() == '' ) {
        all_ok = false;
        err_msg += "\n - Card Numbers cannot be blank";
        fld='couponstart1';
    }else{
        if ( isNaN($("#couponstart1").val()) || isNaN($("#couponstart2").val()) || isNaN($("#couponend1").val()) || isNaN($("#couponend2").val()) ) {
            all_ok = false;
            err_msg += "\n - Card Number has to be numeric";
            fld='couponstart1';
        }else{
            if ( $("#couponstart1").val() < 1 || $("#couponstart2").val() < 1 || $("#couponend1").val() < 1 || $("#couponend2").val() < 1 ) {
                all_ok = false;
                err_msg += "\n - Card Numbers are not correct";
                fld='couponstart1';
            }else if ($("#couponstart1").val().length != 4 || $("#couponstart2").val().length != 4 || $("#couponend1").val().length != 4 || $("#couponend2").val().length < 4){
                all_ok = false;
                err_msg += "\n - Card Numbers are not correct";
                fld='couponstart1';
            }   
        }
    }

    if (all_ok == false){
        alert("The following errors have taken place" + err_msg); 
        setFocus(fld);
    }
    return all_ok;    

}
```

Comment: Where exactly in your code the 4 zeros are throwing the error?

Comment: And you could save lots of testing using regex, like `/\d{4}/.test("0000")` will test for numbers only with exactly 4 digits

Comment: I have no idea how to use regex. This is where the error is being thrown: `}else{
            if ( $("#couponstart1").val() < 1 || $("#couponstart2").val() < 1 || $("#couponend1").val() < 1 || $("#couponend2").val() < 1 ) {
                all_ok = false;
                err_msg += "\n - Card Numbers are not correct";
                fld='couponstart1';
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sad that computers do what we ask, not what we want.

If your input is filled with 0000, and you compare `<` it with the number `1`:  `($("#couponstart1").val() < 1`, javascript will try to parse the value `0000` to the operand type which accounts to `0`. So it is right to say that `0 is lower than 1`and you'll get your error message `Card number are not correct`.

Let's try a different approach:

```
<!-- html -->
<form>
    <p>
        <label for="couponstart1">Coupon Start Part 1</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="4" id="couponstart1" class="validateme" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="couponstart2">Coupon Start Part 2</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="4" id="couponstart2" class="validateme" />
    </p>    
     <p>
        <label for="couponend1">Coupon End Part 1</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="4" id="couponend1" class="validateme" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="couponstart2">Coupon Start End 2</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="4" id="couponend2" class="validateme" />
    </p>
    <button type="button" id="testit">Test</button>
</form>
```

and:

```
/* javascript/jQuery */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#testit").click(function(){
        var rgx = /\d{4}/;
        var allgood = true;
        $("input.validateme").each(function(){
            if( ! rgx.test( $(this).val() ) ){
                alert("Card number for " + ($('label[for="' + $(this).attr("id")  + '"]').text()) + " is not correct!\nPlease use 4 digits all numbers!");

                $(this).select();
                allgood = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if(allgood) alert("All good!");
    });
});
```

Basically we have a form with 4 `inputs` with "validateme" `class`.
With jQuery we loop over the inputs that have this class an run it against the regex `/\d{4}/` which basically will test for a number(`\d`) exactly 4 digits long (`{4}`) meaning from 0000 to 9999. Note that we use the label of the input to identify which field is not right.

Otherwise, all good.

You can fiddle with this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/L8dcgcrs/1/

Comment: aldux, thanx for the response and for the really elegant solution. It works. Question: since I have a couple of other bits of JavaScript together with this one on that page, do you think the change that I made is sufficient enough without any other code change?? (I am not a programmer.) I had just changed `.val() < 1` to `.val() < -1`. And there were no more errors. Or do you think that this will break something else...??

Comment: Comparing with -1 is still useless since your number has to have 4 digits.

Comment: Understood.  But if I change it to -1, that particular error goes away and it correctly catches it if someone enters less than 4 numbers.  Which satisfies both the conditions. Granted your solution is more elegant, but looks like this changing to -1 also works in this scenario. I don't know why it works but it seems to work. Please let me know if any of this seems weird. Thanx for your time.

Comment: Not weird at all. Since 0 is indeed less than -1. It should work with `<=0`as well. But still useless since you check for the length of the sequence in the next test case. Just drop it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the four digits correspond to `$("#couponstart1").val(), $("#couponstart2").val(), $("#couponend1").val(), $("#couponend2").val()` then the problem is that in JavaScript there are two types of comparison operators.

In your first `if` statement you choose to evaluate `if $("#coupontstart1").val() == '' || ...)`. In this case you are using an equality operator which converts the operands if they are not the same type. So using this operator `0 == ''` returns `true`. Instead you could use the strict equality operator `===` in the following manner:

```
 if ( $("#couponstart1").val() === '' || ...)
```

In which case `0 === ''` would return false. This most likely will help you in the first if statement you write as entering `0000` would make all the conditions false and you would proceed to the else block.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that does make sense. Just FYI, this is where the error is being thrown: `}else{
            if ( $("#couponstart1").val() < 1 || $("#couponstart2").val() < 1 || $("#couponend1").val() < 1 || $("#couponend2").val() < 1 ) {
                all_ok = false;
                err_msg += "\n - Card Numbers are not correct";
                fld='couponstart1';
`

Comment: Sorry, the wording of your question confused me since you said that the error was that using zeros made your program complain that it was empty. If all your values are 0, then wouldn't the condition that `.val() < 1` always be true? And if the value is 0 then how does it get past the first `if` statement unless the value is the string '0'?

Comment: I have no idea about your second question, Josh. But you are correct about the first one. Maybe I should have provided a screenshot of the actual webpage. There are 4 fields and each field has to have 4 numbers in it (the last one can have 4 or 5 numbers in it). The numbers can be zero. This set up is working unless I try to put all zeros in any of the fields. I am no programmer, but what I think is happening is when I put all zeros the value of that field is now less than 1. Hence the error. If I put 0001, then no error. So if I change `.val() < 1` to `.val() < -1` then there is no error.